# Reverse Index in SQL

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, nlp

In this assignment, you will create a table of documents and then produce a reverse index for those documents that identifies each document which contains a particular word using SQL.

FYI: In contrast with the provided sample SQL, you will map all the words in the reverse index to lower case (i.e. Python, PYTHON, and python should all end up as "python" in the inverted index).

```
CREATE TABLE docs01 (id SERIAL, doc TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE invert01 (
  keyword TEXT,
  doc_id INTEGER REFERENCES docs01(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here are the one-line documents that you are to insert into docs01:

```
INSERT INTO docs01 (doc) VALUES
('The building blocks of programs'),
('In the next few chapters we will learn more about the vocabulary'),
('sentence structure paragraph structure and story structure of Python'),
('We will learn about the powerful capabilities of Python and how to'),
('compose those capabilities together to create useful programs'),
('There are some lowlevel conceptual patterns that we use to construct'),
('programs These constructs are not just for Python programs they are'),
('part of every programming language from machine language up to the'),
('file or even some kind of sensor like a microphone or GPS In our'),
('initial programs our input will come from the user typing data on');
```

Here is a sample for the first few expected rows of your reverse index:

```
SELECT keyword, doc_id FROM invert01 ORDER BY keyword, doc_id LIMIT 10;
```

| keyword | doc_id |
| --- | --- |
| a | 9 |
| about | 2 |
| about | 4 |
| and | 3 |
| and | 4 |
| are | 6 |
| are | 7 |
| blocks | 1 |
| building | 1 |
| capabilities | 4 |

```
INSERT INTO invert01 (keyword, doc_id)
SELECT
    lower(keyword) AS keyword,
    doc_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        id AS doc_id,
        unnest(string_to_array(doc, ' ')) AS keyword
    FROM docs01
) AS words;
```

I tried this but error is showing that "Keyword 'are' should be in 2 documents and was only in 3 documents".
Please Help me to find the error.

Comment: Not sure on postgres, but SQL Server lets you specify `DESC` on an index, just like with an ORDER BY.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't think he is talking about an index.

Comment: Your query looks good (well, it could be more beautiful, but it works). I guess they want you to slap on a `DISTINCT` so that you report the word only once per sentence, even if it occurs twice.

Comment: Thanks. Its working by Distinct keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77333202/reverse-index-in-sql#comment136333402_77333202), each doc with multiple instances of a keyword, like number 7:

> ('programs These constructs ***are*** not just for Python programs they ***are***'),

causes your query to produce a `(keyword,doc_id)` pairing multiple times:

| keyword | doc_id |
| --- | --- |
| are | 6 |
| are | 7 |
| are | 7 |

because a `SELECT` is by default a `SELECT ALL` that accepts duplicates. You can prevent that by switching to a [`SELECT DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) that discards duplicates.

You also don't need to use a subquery to apply `lower()` and you can use [`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.35.1.1.1) to split documents directly into rows of keywords, instead of splitting into an array first and then calling `unnest()`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/F_0A6Rew):

```sql
INSERT INTO invert01 (keyword, doc_id)
SELECT DISTINCT lower(string_to_table(doc, ' ')) AS keyword,
                id AS doc_id
FROM docs01;
```

Result

```sql
SELECT keyword, doc_id FROM invert01 WHERE keyword='are' 
ORDER BY keyword, doc_id LIMIT 10;
```

| keyword | doc_id |
| --- | --- |
| are | 6 |
| are | 7 |